# Aptana Studio vs. Eclipse + Aptana

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana

1. Are there any differences between the two for using with PHP?
2. Which is better (lighter, snappier)?
3. Can I install Eclipse plugins in Aptana?
4. How good is Aptana beta 3 and does it have jQuery, HTML5 and CSS3 support?
5. Does Aptana have code folding for PHP (braces closing)?

Comment: It's wrong that this gets deleted! This is a good programming question, related to programming for programmers. It shouldn't cause huge debate as he has only referenced two different software for one language!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not that I'm any expert :), but I have used Aptana and Eclipse for years now, including my current setup which entails a stand-alone Aptana install for Ruby, Python, PHP and HTML 5-y stuff as well as an Eclipse install with the Aptana plugin for Java/ColdFusion work. I wanted to respond with my thoughts on your questions. I hope they are helpful!

1. Assuming you are using Aptana's PHP plugin, no.
2. I have found Aptana to be slightly snappier than Eclipse + Aptana but not markedly so.
3. Absolutely! It's just another (prettier) Eclipse install.
4. Aptana Studio 3 is in the Release Candidate stage. It's been solid and pretty damn close to feature complete (has HTML5, CSS3, advanced JavaScript (incl. jQuery, etc.), JS debugging, etc.).
5. Not 100% sure but I recall they do.

If you care to, check out Titanium Studio. In January, Appcelerator purchased Aptana. This is the 'new' Aptana Studio and contains all the same features and functionality of Studio 3 but also adds in Appcelerator's Titanium Developer mobile SDKs and features. It's pretty cool!

I hope this helps you out a bit!

Best,
Craig